# PHP Calling a static function

Tags: php, static, function-call

Given the following code I am looking for pro's and con's of calling $this->myStaticFunc(); vs self::myStaticFunc();

```
class MyClass

  private function myPrivateFunc() {
    ...
    $this->myStaticFunc(); // or self::myStaticFunc();
    ...
  }

  // no need to tell me that i can't use $this in here
  public static function myStaticFunc() { ... }

}

// access static function
MyClass::myStaticFunc();
```

Comment: giving you zero information and want to know if I should purchase a black or a blue car ...

Comment: They serve totally different purposes.... if your function needs to work against the instance, then you call it as an instance function; if not, then you can use a static function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cons of using `$this->myStaticFunction()` are:

- It doesn't clearly indicate what you intend (`->` indicates you are doing something with an object, *but you aren't*),
- It may wind up calling something you didn't expect,
- It will likely confuse the reader (all the reader will be able to determine for sure is that the author doesn't understand basic OO principles),
- And it's simply *wrong*: static functions belong to classes, not objects.  Call them through a class (including `self`), not an object.

The only possible pro is that you may want to override the static function in a child class, but this indicates that the function belongs to the *object* and not the class.  In that case it would be more appropriate to use an instance method.